# Changeing imageicons instantly in for loop

Tags: for-loop, imageicon

I am creating a minesweeper in java. Now my problem is, when the game ends, i want to reveal where the bombs were when the user clicks on one. So i decided to write a function which will be called when one of the bombs are being clicked on. This function will loop over the table(10x10 grid layout), and checks if a tile is a bomb or not. If so, it's image icon will be changed to another one, and i will call a "Thread.sleep(200)". In this way the bombs will appear from the top to the bottom. My problem is, that changing ImageIcons in java is not instant. If i code like i mentioned above the "Thread.sleep(200) will be called, and i have to wait for that, but the icons only show at the end(i suppose when the user gets the input again). How can i reveal the image icons while in for loop?

Here is my code(gombok is my JButton array that i want to change the icon of):

```
public void gameover() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
                if(tiles[i][j].isIsbomb()) {
                    gombok[i][j].setIcon(bomb);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dispose();
        System.out.println("Game Over");
    }
```